# How to use the Free Starter Edition of Sigasi's VHDL IDE

Tags: digital-logic, design, vhdl

I downloaded sigasis ide for vhdl lastnight and i opened up the tutorial vhdl folder and tried to hit the run button (the green play button im assuming) and i got some menus and i just put some stuff in and now when i hit the play button i get this message.

"Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\Cameron\workspaceSigasi\test\workbench.vhd": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Im new to VHDL so if you would be so kind as to run me through what software I need to just simulate the code that would be great. Im learning VHDL because we never really learned it in the class i took on logic desgin and id love to say to a prospective employer that i know something about VHDL design.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: as far as i know sigasi ide is just an ide (in form of an eclipse plugin), no simulation environment or synthesis tool is included. so if you hit a simulation button anywhere in the menu you should set up the path to your simulation program (e.g. ModelSim) first or nothing will happen because sigasi cant find the correct application to run...

Comment: @Leon Heller: IMHO, VHDL is real electronic hardware design.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download a simulator. Sigasi is only for design entry (typing and inspecting code). Look here for a list of free simulators: http://www.sigasi.com/faq/which-free-vhdl-simulator-can-i-use